# yushkas bris aniversary

Tags: brit-milah, history, calendar, christianity, myths

Is it true that new years is the aniversary of yushka's bris

Comment: Now, what is the relevance of this with respect to Jewish life or learning? Are some people machmir to observe nittel on the day of the bris as well? :-)

Comment: Sure, we don't want to do a "vach nacht" for him!

Comment: I'm closing this so that the community user doesn't keep bringing it up, hoping it will finally get an upvoted answer.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Is that a valid close reason?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's also truly off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Dr. Shnayer Leiman has a fascinating shiur on a related topic (the mysterious "fast of the 9th of Teves"), and one of the points he brings up is the complete unreliability of the December 25 date. It's worth a listen [here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/715371/Dr._Shnayer_Leiman/Jewish_Perspectives_on_Early_Christianity_-_Nittel,_the_Ninth_of_Teves_and_Pope_Simon_Peter_-_Cong_Beth_Abraham), at the 33:00 mark.

Comment: I think it's well accepted, even within Christianity, that the Dec. 25th date is baseless.

Comment: @TRiG Maybe in theory, but certainly not in practice. (I guess the marketing folks had to pick *some* day, right?)

Comment: And the birthday of Sol Invictus seemed appropriate.

Comment: @TRiG who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Well **if** he was born on Dec 25 then 8 days later on New Years would be the anniversary of his Bris.

Comment: So the question then is whether he was indeed born on December 25th.

Comment: Why? He might have been an unhealthy baby (especially if he was born in a manger), and had to have his bris postponed...

Comment: @Alex Alternatively, he was born Mahul.